# How do I add a row to a pandas dataframe if conditions in prior rows are met?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

Each row of the df is a line item for an order.  If an order contains fruit, I need to add a row for a "fruit handling charge", e.g.:

Input DF:

| Order | Item | Is_Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Apple | TRUE |
| 100 | Bread | FALSE |
| 100 | Eggs | FALSE |
| 101 | Bread | FALSE |
| 101 | Cookies | FALSE |
| 102 | Pear | TRUE |
| 102 | Apple | TRUE |
| 103 | Onion | FALSE |
| 103 | Bread | FALSE |
| 103 | Eggs | FALSE |
| 103 | Cookies | FALSE |
| 104 | Pear | TRUE |
| 104 | Banana | TRUE |

Output DF should be:

| Order | Item | Is_Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Apple | TRUE |
| 100 | Bread | FALSE |
| 100 | Eggs | FALSE |
| 100 | Handling Fee |  |
| 101 | Bread | FALSE |
| 101 | Cookies | FALSE |
| 102 | Pear | TRUE |
| 102 | Apple | TRUE |
| 102 | Handling Fee |  |
| 103 | Onion | FALSE |
| 103 | Bread | FALSE |
| 103 | Eggs | FALSE |
| 103 | Cookies | FALSE |
| 104 | Pear | TRUE |
| 104 | Banana | TRUE |
| 104 | Handling Fee |  |

I can do this with a for loop using iterrows with if statements and tracking variables, but I was hoping there is a simpler, more elegant way to achieve this.

Here's the inelegant version:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# If one or more of the items in a single order is fruit, then add a fruit handling charge.

file = r"D:\Dropbox\Python\Tests\fruittest.xlsx"

df =  pd.read_excel(file)

# Initiate tracking variables
prior_order = 0
add_handling = False
df2 = df # Copy the df for the result

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0: #Special case for first row
        add_handling = row['Is_Fruit'] 
    
    elif row['Order'] == prior_order: #if we're still on the same order
         add_handling = add_handling | row['Is_Fruit'] # Boolean operator changes to True if this item is fruit
        
    elif (row['Order'] != prior_order): # if it's the first line of a new order
        if add_handling: #If there was fruit in the prior order
            new_row = {'Order':prior_order, 'Item':'Handling Fee'}
            df2 = df2.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
            
        add_handling = row['Is_Fruit'] # Reset the tracker based on the first item of the new order

    prior_order = row['Order'] #Update the order number tracking before going to the next item in the for loop

# After the loop finishes, handle the last row
if add_handling: #If there was fruit in the last order
    new_row = {'Order':prior_order, 'Item':'Handling Fee'}
    df2 = df2.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    
    
# Sort the result by Order when we're done
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Order'],ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

***sorry i guess these codes be useful this time***

```
con = pd.DataFrame()
for gr,grframe in df.groupby(["Order","Date","Customer"]):
    if True in grframe["Is_Fruit"].values:
        handling_fee_row = grframe.iloc[[0],:].copy()
        handling_fee_row[["Item", "Is_Fruit", "Prod_Code", "Price"]] = ["Handling Fee", False, "HF1", 5.25]
        con = pd.concat([con, grframe, handling_fee_row])
    else:
        con = pd.concat([con, grframe])
        
con.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)   
con
```

Comment: I have more columns than those shown in the simple example, e.g. Date, Customer Name, etc. How would I modify the function to keep the values in those columns (assume these values are the same across each order? :)

Comment: can you give an example for your data and expected output ?

Comment: Here's a more realistic -- though still simplified -- dataset:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywh8h0g8sflrjyo/fruittest2.xlsx?dl=0). See the input and output tabs.

Comment: i added new answer you can check this

Comment: Yes, this works! The multi-column groupby is what was eluding me before. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out that your solution only works on simple data. I'm having trouble generalizing it to more complex data.  This input / expected output file demonstrates the problem: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn9ehga50mltrn3/fruittest5.xlsx?dl=0).  I'm getting a "must produce aggregated value" error even though customers and dates are unique per order.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, your revised code does generalize well to the larger dataset.  You, sir, are a genius! Thanks again for your help.